# How to rename the header.actions field in Material-table?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am currently using material-table library but it seems that renaming the action field is not possible? I need your help to do that.
library: https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/localization
I found the property that is responsible: HEADER.ACTIONS

I tried the solution below but no results.

Thank you in advance. I appreciate any help.

```
          {
            title: 'Fragetyp',
            field: 'followupType',
            cellStyle: {
              color: palette.tableBodyColor,
              fontSize: '1.3rem'
            },
            render: (rowData) => <Subject />
          },
          {
            title: 'actions',
            field: 'header.actions',
            cellStyle: {
              color: palette.tableBodyColor,
              fontSize: '1.3rem'
            }
          }
```

I want to rename the "actions" field header name into another language.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, you just have to  add localization and then header > actions.

```
<MaterialTableStyled
       localization={{
          header: {
            actions: 'Aktionen'
          }
        }}
      ... >
```